# Get content from specified tags in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible in angular 2+ component get content of some tags? Something like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>My component <p><ng-content from='forp'/></p><span><ng-content from='forspan'/></span></div>',
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Then we write

```
    <my-component>
      <forp>Content for p-tag</forp>
      <forspan>Content for span-tag</forspan>
    </my-component>
```

And it build as

```
    <div>
      My component 
      <p>Content for p-tag</p>
      <span>Content for span-tag</span>
    </div>
```

?

Comment: May be you need to see the details about [angular directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is it possible. You can create a component and take HTML when you will use you component like this:

```
<my-comp>
  <some-comp></some-comp>
  <some-other-comp></some-other-comp>
</my-comp>
```

MyComponent html will look like this:

```
<div>
  // some html code
  <ng-content select="some-other-comp"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="some-comp"></ng-content>
  // some html code
</div>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Oh, yes, it helps! But I thought that I can do it without creating other components.

Comment: Yes but only one html will be inject in your component and ng-content will not have select attribute.